# Rails + Passenger: Invalid Route name, already in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I'm attempting to host a Rails 4 application with Apache and Passenger on a RHEL 6.3 machine. My application is accessible on the IP address on the server when the httpd service is running, but gives the Rails "Something went wrong" page when I try to access a page. The application runs correctly when hosted via rails server. I'm hoping someone with a little more hosting experience can help me out and tell me where I'm going wrong.

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf includes:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.20/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.20
    PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
```

which ruby returns `/usr/bin/ruby`.

/etc/httpd/conf.d/server.conf includes:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/service/public
  RailsEnv production
  <Directory /var/www/service/public
   AllowOverride all
   Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

where service is the name of my folder my Rails Project is in.

The passenger error in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log is:

```
App 23360 stdout:
[ 2015-10-05 12:05:43.4683 23295/7fd764072700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:303 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/service: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
Error ID: aa70e16a
Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-41xm1e.html
Message from application: Invalid route name, already in use: 'base'
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created (ArgumentError)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:538:in `add_route'...
```

I've pared down my routes in an attempt to find out why it thinks I have more than one named "base", since this is all I have in my routes:

```
Service::Application.routes.draw do

  match 'home' => 'activation#register', :as => :base

end
```

where home is just a test link that displays "SUCCESS".

I'm pretty baffled - I have no idea why Passenger thinks that I have multiple routes named base when there is only one. I am wondering if the routes are somehow being loaded multiple times.

I am not able to use RVM, yum, or any other code mangers due to being behind a corporate firewall. This, unfortunately, is nonnegotiable.

I appreciate any and all help, thanks very much. Let me know if anyone needs me to post more details.

Comment: how does server.conf get loaded? is it maybe get included twice?

Comment: in the httpd.conf file, I have `Include conf.d/*.conf` but I don't see any other references to server.conf or including other .conf files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passenger author here. I think you are running into [issue #1596](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1596#issuecomment-137203230) where a slight change in behavior causes some applications to initialize Rails twice. A fix is planned for the next version, but for now you can simply downgrade to 5.0.15.

Comment: Fixed the problem neatly to downgrade to 5.0.15. Thanks so much for the help! :)